How to auto repeat ImportHTML with multiple URLS in Google Sheets
I am working on using ImportHTML in a google sheet right now, and am using it to import data that is always 6 columns wide, but is dynamic in length:
Data
The formula I am using is:
=IMPORTHTML(A1,"table",1,"en_US")
In Column A, i want to be able to add as many URLS as I want, and for it to add all of the data to a large table 6 wide by however long. I know how to add arrays using =Vstack, but i dont know how to use a dynamic list of URLS instead of just one.
URLS
Text: https://ftc-events.firstinspires.org/2023/USIAMCM1/qualifications
Added bonus if its possible to remove the text Column Labels that is imported with each data set.
text: Match #   Red     Blue        Score


You may try:
=reduce(tocol(,1),tocol(A:A,1),lambda(a,c,vstack(a,let(Σ,importhtml(c,"table",),filter(Σ,index(Σ,,1)<>"Match #")))))



this is great. reviewing your last few answers has helped expand my use of lambdas in google sheets. can you help me understand the tocol(,1) as initial value for the reduce function?

tocol(,1) is a way to provide null value as a reduce() header; also it only works in conjunction with vstack() bcoz if you use the same in a regular cell, its goin' to be an error

I don't think there's a way to dynamically feed an importhtml multiple URLs but if you can predict the number of URLs you think you would need to accommodate, you could use something like this (this is designed for up to 6, and it will also strip out the column labels assuming they all start with "Match"):
=QUERY(query({
iferror({IMPORTHTML(A1,"table",1,"en_US")},{"","","","","",""});
iferror({IMPORTHTML(A2,"table",1,"en_US")},{"","","","","",""});
iferror({IMPORTHTML(A3,"table",1,"en_US")},{"","","","","",""});
iferror({IMPORTHTML(A4,"table",1,"en_US")},{"","","","","",""});
iferror({IMPORTHTML(A5,"table",1,"en_US")},{"","","","","",""});
iferror({IMPORTHTML(A6,"table",1,"en_US")},{"","","","","",""})}),
"select * where Col1 is not null and not Col1 starts with 'Match'")


@rockinfreakshow 's answer is the way to go.
